# Make FFmpeg output a similar video quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, bitrate

I'm using FFmpeg in my program to cut a video. This is the command my program executed:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:04:35.000 out.avi
```

Quality and size of out.avi are MUCH lower than in.avi. How can I tell FFmpeg to keep the quality of the input file? I don't want to use -c copy because then the video will start with black frames.

Here is the output without -c copy (command above) http://pastebin.com/JYYRsFsQ

Here is the output of the command with -c copy `ffmpeg -i in.avi -ss 00:00:05.000 -c copy -to 00:04:35.000 out.avi`

output with -c copy: http://pastebin.com/wXPhBSYj

Comment: Please include the `ffmpeg` command and complete console output from the command that uses `-c copy`. Do all players show the black frames?

Comment: I included both commands and their output now. I only tested VLC which shows black frames, but plays the sound. I think it is because there is no key frame at second 5 (where I start cutting). It is black for like 3 to 4 seconds. VLC is the only player I care about so no use to test any other.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ffmpeg -i inFile -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a copy -ss starttime -to endtime outFile` now. It seems to encode the video in good quality and reasonable size (exactly what you'd expect from libx264).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-codec copy`

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy

Stream copy just does muxing operations without encoding. The quality changes come from differences in encoding, lower bitrate/audio sample rate.

Example of this command:

`ffmpeg -i in.avi -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:04:35.000 -codec copy out.avi`